# Cannot read from file

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem reading an integer from a file. As for my knowledge it should work. Can you tell me what have I done wrong here?

```
    int fileCount = 0;
    ifstream listFileStream ( fileName );

    if ( listFileStream.is_open() ) {

            listFileStream >> fileCount;
            cout << fileCount;

    }
```

It only prints 0 even though the first line of the file is 28.

Comment: Try reading a line at a time. see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: If I change the variable type to string it gives this... 'fileCount = "ÿþ2"'

Comment: @SankaD I think you have some unexpected characters at the start of your file. Could even be the Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Comment: Ah... I deleted the file and copied the content into a new file with the same name and now it works... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should always check that you read attempt was successful:

```
if (listFileStream >> fileCount) {
    process(fileCount);
}
```

If the read isn't successful you can try to recover from it or report an error. Here is one way you might try to recover: restore the stream to good state and ignore the first character:

```
listFileStream.clear();
listFileStream.ignore();
```

Without restoring the stream to a good state all input attempts would be ignored. Once the offending character is removed you would retry the read.